# character error fortran 90

Tags: fortran90

I'm struggling with a small program, I can't find how to correct one mistake.

My program:

```
program calcul

! ce programme permet d'effectuer des opérations mathématique de base

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL::x,y

character(len=1)::op

character(len=16)::op_msg

write(*,*)"entrer le type d'opération à effectuer(+,-,/,x,*)"       

read(*,*)op

write(*,*)"entrer le premier nombre de l'opération"

read(*,*)x

write(*,*)"entrer le deuxième nombre de l'opération"

read(*,*)y

if(op=="+") then

  write(*,*)x,"plus",y,"egale",x+y

    else if(op=="-")then

      write(*,*)x,"moin",y,"egale",x-y

    else if ((op==("*").or.("x")) then

      write(*,*)x,"multiplie par",y,"egale",x*y

        else if (op=="/")then

          write(*,*)x,"divise par",y,"egale",x/y

else

write(*,*)"erreur:operation incorrecte"

end if

end program calcul
```

The error message:

```
calculette.f90:21.26:

 else if ((op==("*").or.("x")) then

                                     1

Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Any idea? I don't understand why "x" is an invalid character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if ((op==("*").or.op==("x")) then
```

You are evaluating two separate conditions, so each one needs a "left" and "right" side.